# Java objects with data members created dymaically

Tags: java, class, object

I have seen in Javascript ,

```
var obj = {
}
function addMember(memberName,value) {
    obj[memberName] = value;
}
```

ie. objects can have members whose name is not known before at object/class declaration.So is there a similar way in Java ,where i can add new members to an object with unknown name?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828160/adding-a-field-to-java-class

Generally it means "no".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a Map.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(memberName, value);
```

Comment: You're not adding members to an object, as was asked how to do

Comment: objects don't have names. fields and local variable can have names like `obj` (in the example) or `map`

Comment: @MStodd can you say how the implementation of adding members in JS differs from an associative array or map?

Comment: @PeterLawrey it doesn't.  In JS, you can add a member with obj[name] = value, then access it with obj.name.  You can't do this in Java.  The question was "...is there a similar way in Java ,where i can add new members to an object..."

Comment: So by this way it is possible to add members with unknown names?

Comment: @JinuJD When the names are unknown, what do you want it to do?